# Getting the x and y values of a filled pixel position in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, pixel

I am trying to replicate this effect, but I find the tutorial provided extremely hard to follow: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/InteractiveTypographyEffects/index3.html

Basically, I want to fill text to the canvas really quickly (like for a single frame), get the image data (scanning the whole page's pixels one by one) and IF a pixel is filled, push an particle in it's x and y position.

I know how the getImageData works and how to scan pixels one by one, like this:

```
var numPixels = imageData.width*imageData.height; 

for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) { 
    pixels[i*4] = 255; // Red 
    pixels[i*4+1] = 0; // Green 
    pixels[i*4+2] = 0; // Blue 
    pixels[i*4+3] = 255; // Alpha 
};
```

HOWEVER, I want to be able to retrieve their x and y positions. I tried something like this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < imageData.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < imageData.height; y++){
        var i = x * 4 + y * 4 * imageData.width;
        if (i === 255) {
            particles.push(new Particle(x, y); //Push a particle if the pixel is filled with any color
        }
    }
}
```

But, unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.. I've been stuck on this for quite some time, so all ideas and suggestions are more then welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to quantize the pixels to form a grid where you can place your particles (ref. the demo you link to).

To do this you simply define a grid by setting width and height of a single grid cell. Then you pick a pixel from each grid corner (or center etc.) to check if you have a pixel set or not. If you do then create a particle for that position.

Just play around with font position, font size and grid size to get a visually pleasing result.

See following code for details and for demo:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    width = ctx.canvas.width,
    height = ctx.canvas.height,

    particles = [],
    gridX = 8,
    gridY = 8;

function Particle(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// fill some text
ctx.font = 'bold 80px sans-serif';
ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0';
ctx.fillText("STACKOVERFLOW", 5, 120);

// now parse bitmap based on grid
var idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

// use a 32-bit buffer as we are only checking if a pixel is set or not
var buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer);

// using two loops here, single loop with index-to-x/y is also an option
for(var y = 0; y < height; y += gridY) {
  for(var x = 0; x < width; x += gridX) {

    //buffer32[] will have a value > 0 (true) if set, if not 0=false
    if (buffer32[y * width + x]) {
      particles.push(new Particle(x, y));
    }
  }
}

// render particles
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

particles.forEach(function(p) {
  ctx.fillRect(p.x - 2, p.y - 2, 4, 4); // just squares here
})
```

```css
#canvas {background:#000}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=180></canvas>
```

Comment: just one more question. I want to set up a function and display a different letter from the english alphabet on every 2s. I guess I have to put the pixel operation in a function and set it to display a different letter with setInterval? How would you proceed?

Comment: No problem! Just use a string, fetch one char per time and go to next index and render. I'll suggest open a new question which you can get a more detailed answer by.